# MonogDB 2.6 equivalent for group by to get distinct count

Tags: mongodb

I do have below output from MongoDB query:

```
db.campaign.find({},{"_id":0,"Name":1, "Info.subscriber_id":1})
```

yields:

```
{ "Info" : [ { "subscriber_id" : "" } ], "Name" : "C1" }
{ "Info" : [ { "subscriber_id" : "1" } ], "Name" : "C2" }
{ "Info" : [ { "subscriber_id" : "1" } ], "Name" : "C3" }
{ "Info" : [ { "subscriber_id" : "2" } ], "Name" : "C4" }
```

I want to find out group by equivalent for distinct count in MongoDB as:

```
select subscriber, count(*) totalCount, count(distinct Name) distinctCount 
FROM campaign GROUP BY subscriber;
```

I've constructed below MongoDB query to get the result-set equivalent to above sql query:

```
db.campaign.aggregate([
    {"$group":{
        "_id":{
            "subscriber": "$Info.subscriber_id",
            "Name":"$Name"
        },
        "count":{"$sum": 1}
    }},
    {"$group":{
        "_id":{
            "subscriber": "$_id.subscriber"
        },
        "totalCount":{"$sum":"$count"},
        "distinctCount":{"$sum: 1"}
    }}
]);
```

But while executing above mongodb query I am getting error like:

> 2016-05-20T14:50:47.973+0530 SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

If I execute only 1st group from above query, I am getting the result set.

```
db.campaign.aggregate([
    {"$group":{
        "_id":{
            "subscriber": "$Info.subscriber_id",
            "Name":"$Name"
        },
        "count":{"$sum": 1}
    }}
]);

{ "_id" : { "subscriber" : [ "" ], "Name" : "c1" }, "count" : 1 } 
{ "_id" : { "subscriber" : [ "1" ], "Name" : "c1" }, "count" : 1 } 
{ "_id" : { "subscriber" : [ "1" ], "Name" : "c3" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "subscriber" : [ "2" ], "Name" : "c2" }, "count" : 1 } 
{ "_id" : { "subscriber" : [ "2" ], "Name" : "c4" }, "count" : 1 } 
{ "_id" : { "subscriber" : [ "3" ], "Name" : "c3" }, "count" : 1 }
```

Can someone please do let me know what is wrong with my query. I am using MongoDB2.6.

Comment: check in second group "distinctCount":{"$sum": 1}  not "distinctCount":{"$sum: 1"}

Comment: Ahhh, got it. I didn't figure this out. Thanks for pointing this out. Now its working.